# Join two database table zend framework 1.12

Tags: mysql, database, zend-framework

I have used two mysql database in our projects. one database is connected the basic user information and another database used to store the daily  activities. Now need to combine two database tables .

fetch user daily activity with user information , then need to join with master databases.

I found the solution in in PHP. But i want the solution on zend framework 1.12 ?

I used multidb functionality used to fetch different action .

```
resources.multidb.tb.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
  resources.multidb.tb.host = "localhost"
  resources.multidb.tb.username = "root"
  resources.multidb.tb.password = ""
  resources.multidb.tb.dbname = "@@@@@"
  resources.multidb.tb.default = true

  resources.multidb.pl.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
  resources.multidb.pl.host = "localhost"
  resources.multidb.pl.username = "root"
  resources.multidb.pl.password = ""
  resources.multidb.pl.dbname = "#######"
```

But I want to query for join 2 tables in different databases.

**example**

> SELECT db1.table1.somefield, db2.table1.somefield FROM db1.table1
>   INNER JOIN db2.table1 ON db1.table1.someid = db2.table1.someid WHERE
>   db1.table1.somefield = 'queryCrit';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having in mind [Zend's Join Inner declaration](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/classes/Zend_Db_Select.html#method_joinInner):

```
public function joinInner($name, $cond, $cols = self::SQL_WILDCARD, $schema = null)
```

And being '$this', for example, a Zend_Db_Table_Abstract implementation with adapter set to db1 (with _setAdapter()) and schema to "@@@@@" (this is not really necessary because it'll use it as default):

```
$select = $this->select(true)->setIntegrityCheck(false)
               ->from(array('t1'=>'table1'),array('somefield')
               ->joinInner(array('t1b'=>'table1'),
                          't1.someid = t1b.someid',
                           array('t1b.somefield'),
                           '######')
               ->where('t1.somefield = ?', $queryCrit);
```

Please, note the the fourth parameter of the Inner Join method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you, please, accept the answer as correct in order to other users know it? Thanks.